# What is/are the asymptote(s) of the straight line?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

**Definition of Asymptote**[Calculus and Analytic Geometry, *Thomas, Finney*, 9E]

[image]

What is the asymptote of a straight line,y=mx+c?

**My attempt**

Every parallel line meets at infinity in the extended real line. Hence Every parallel line to the line $y=mx+c$ are asymptotes of $y=mx+c$. Therefore asymptotes are of the form $y=mx+d,d\in \mathbb R.$

Is there any error in my understanding?

Comment: What’s your definition of an asymptote?

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In projective terms, two parallel lines intersect at a point at infinity, but they have different tangents at that point (the tangents are the lines themselves). The tangents are called asymptotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between two straight lines remains constant. The only straight line such that its distance from the graph of $y=mx+c$ approaches $0$ is the line $y=mx+c$ itself (in which case that distance is actually $0$ everywhere).

Comment: But, won't the parallel lines meet at infinity?

Comment: That depends upon the definitions of “meet” and “infinity”. What I wrote is independent of that.